# How do create a custom button by adding an overlay to the Viewer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pdftron

I want to add a custom save button as on overlay to my file viewer application. I created the button in the SaveButton.jsx file
code snippet

```js
export default function SaveButton({ text, onPress }) {
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{text}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>;
}
```

And I want to add this to my App.jsx file. But I get an error JSX expressions must have one parent element - when I remove the View tag and if I add the  tag it doesn't render anything.

```js
return (<View>
        <DocumentView
          document={filepath}
          />
        <SaveButton>onPress={() => {
                text="Save"
                // Manual Save
                this._viewer.saveDocument().then((filePath) => {
                console.log('saveDocument:', filePath);
              });
              }}</SaveButton>
        </View>
            );
        }
```

How do I make it render the save button?
Is there a better way to add the overlay button?
The expected UI for save button is [image]
Any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We ran your code and came up with a solution by adding styles and editing syntax. You can play around with the styles to suit your needs.

In `App.js` `render()` function:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <DocumentView
      ref={(c) => this._viewer = c}
      document={this.state.docPath}
    />
    <View style={styles.button}>
      <SaveButton text="Save" onPress={() => {
        // Manual Save
        this._viewer.saveDocument().then((filePath) => {
          console.log('saveDocument:', filePath);
        });
      }}>
      </SaveButton>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

The styles for `App.js`:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // For the view that wraps both DocumentView and the parent View of SaveButton
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  // For the parent View of SaveButton 
  button: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 150,
    right: 30,
    margin: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 50,
    height: 30,
  }
});
```

In `SaveButton.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function SaveButton({ text, onPress}) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.buttonView}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // For the TouchableOpacity that SaveButton uses
    buttonView: {
        height: 30,
        width: 50,
    },
    // For the Text that SaveButton uses
    text: {
        fontWeight: "bold",
        color: "blue",
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<SaveButton>onPress={() => {` should be `<SaveButton onPress={() => {`